# How to count li elements in DOM in angular?

Tags: angular, list, count, slice

**Question**: How can I count the current number of displayed **li** elements in DOM?

```
    <ul *ngFor="let l of givenList.slice(0,showmorenumbers); let i= index">
      <li>{{l}}</li>
    </ul>

<button (click)="showmore()"> show more</button>
<button (click)="showless()"> showLess</button>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question? @Laxmee

Comment: I have two buttons as above. I want to show a fixed number of items in a list (say 5) where showmorenumbers = 5 in the above code.  when showmore  button is clicked, it  adds  5 more items in the list . My challenge is to hide showmore button when the complete list is rendered (after showmore is clicked a couple of times). For this I want to keep track of how many items have already been displayed in the DOM. I hope that makes sense. @Muthupriya

Comment: For that you will use the index value and length of your array. For example: Hide your showmore button if this **i == givenList.length-1**  condition satisfy. I hope this will help you out. @Laxmee

Answer (score 0):

Number of li elements in DOM can be obtained with usage of plain JS.
Following should do the work:

```
document.querySelectorAll('li').length
```

However as @Muthupriya mentioned in the comment section, this probably is not the best way of solving your problem.

I'd suggest creating additional variable (or using existing `showmorenumbers`) to track number of displayed items (let's say `numberOfDisplayedItems`). It can be incremented in `showmore` method.

If `numberOfDisplayedItems === givenList.length` then *show more* button should be hidden. Also `numberOfDisplayedItems` should never be bigger than `givenList.length`, so keep that in mind while incrementing `numberOfDisplayedItems`.

Answer (score 0):

For Performance when the list gets bigger, it would not be ideal to execute functions on your html ie the line `givenList.slice(0,showmorenumbers)`. ANy change in the DOM will cause this function to be called and this could cause reduced performance of your app.

Consider using [observables](https://angular.io/guide/observables) for your. Example in your case this can be handled as below

### In TS File

Import necessary imports, make sure to import `combineLatest` from `rxjs` and NOT `rxjs/operators`

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { combineLatest, Observable, of, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
```

Declare the Observable

```
givenList$: Observable<string[]> = of([
  'Item 1', 
  'Item 2', 
  'Item 3', 
  'Item 4',
  'Item 4'
]);
```

Declare increment, minimum and maximum quantity of items to display as [BehaviorSubjects](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject)

```
incrementSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(5);
incrementAction$ = this.incrementSubject$.asObservable();
minQuantitySubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(5);
minQuantityAction$ = this.minQuantitySubject$.asObservable();
maxQuantitySubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(20);
maxQuantityAction$ = this.maxQuantitySubject$.asObservable();
currentQuantity = this.minQuantitySubject$.value;
```

Declare an observable to track the current quantity

```
currentQuantity$ = combineLatest([
  this.incrementAction$, 
  this.minQuantityAction$,
  this.maxQuantityAction$ ]).pipe(
    map(([increment, minQuantity, maxQuantity]) => {
      this.currentQuantity = Math.min(
        Math.max(minQuantity , this.currentQuantity + increment),
        maxQuantity
      )
      return this.currentQuantity
    })
  )
```

Declare Filtered list

```
filteredList$: Observable<string[]> = combineLatest([
  this.givenList$, this.currentQuantity$]).pipe(
    map(([givenList, quantity]) => givenList.slice(0, quantity))
  )
```

### In your HTML

You can now use the `async` pipe to subscribe. This way we will not have not need to unsubscribe to avoid memory leaks as angular will do that for us

```
<ul *ngFor="let l of filteredList$ | async; let i= index">
  <li>{{ i }} : {{l}}</li>
</ul>
```

Now to change parameters, we would simply need to call the next function in `incrementSubject$` passing in a value `incrementSubject$.next(5)` This will trigger a change detection making the DOM to be reevaluated

```
<button (click)='incrementSubject$.next(5)'>Increment 5</button>
<button (click)='incrementSubject$.next(-5)'>Reduce 5</button>
<button (click)='minQuantitySubject$.next(3)'>Make Min 3</button>
<button (click)='minQuantitySubject$.next(5)'>Make Min 5</button>
```

With this reactive programing, we may even use `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` to improve the app performance more

See [Example here on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mjzskn)